# Nginx container 502 Bad Gateway

Tags: docker, ssl, nginx, nexus

I know this has been asked before and I've probably read most of these posts, but I am unable to get a combination working.

I am trying to use Nginx as an HTTPS reverse proxy to front Sonatype Nexus 3. Both Nexus and Nginx are containers running on a Linux (Fedora Server) docker host (192.168.60.204 / svr1.domain.com).

- I can navigate to Nginx (https://svr1.domain.com) from another PC
  (192.168.40.10)
- I can navigate to Nexus (http://svr1.domain.com:8081) from another PC
  (192.168.40.10)
- I can navigate to Nexus (http://nexus.domain.com:8081) from another
  PC (192.168.40.10)

However, when I enable `proxy_pass` I get `502 Bad Gateway`
Running `docker logs --tail 50 --follow --timestamps nginx-nexus` from the docker host, I get:

```
[error] 6#6: *1 connect() failed (113: Host is unreachable) while connecting to upstream, client: 192.168.60.1, server: nexus.domain.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://192.168.60.204:8081/", host: "nexus.domain.com"
```

192.168.60.1 is the default gateway for the network the Docker host is on so I have no idea why it appears to be trying to connect to this.

nexus.domain.com is a CNAME pointing to the Docker host.

I can connect to the Nginx container using `docker exec -it nginx-nexus sh` (Thanks @arik) and successfully ping `nexus.domain.com`.

I've tried many permutations of `nginx.conf` as you can see from the commented out code:

```
client_max_body_size      4G;

server {
  listen *:80;
  location /  {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
  }
}

upstream foo{
  #insert your hosts ip here
  server nexus.domain.com:8081;
}

server {
  listen                  443 ssl;
  server_name             nexus.domain.com;

  ssl_certificate         /etc/nginx/certs/nexus.crt.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key     /etc/nginx/certs/nexus.key.pem;
  ssl_protocols           TLSv1.2;
  ssl_ciphers             HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;

  location / {
    #resolver              127.0.0.11 valid=5s;
    proxy_pass            http://nexus.domain.com:8081/;
    #proxy_redirect        off;
    #proxy_set_header      Host $http_host;
    #proxy_set_header      Host $host;
    #proxy_set_header      X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header      X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    #proxy_set_header      X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    proxy_set_header      X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
  }
}
```

I'd like to think the Docker networking is correct as I have another working container using nginx is a similar way.

If anyone can shed some light on what I have wrong, I'd be most grateful.
T.I.A

### Update 1

As per advise from @Arix in comments, under `location / {`  I added:

```
resolver 1.1.1.1 1.0.0.1 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 208.67.222.222 208.67.220.220 valid=60s;
```

With the following error:

```
$ docker logs --tail 50 --follow --timestamps nginx-nexus
2020-06-26T13:14:52.105017039Z 2020/06/26 13:14:52 [error] 6#6: *1 connect() failed (113: Host is unreachable) while connecting to upstream, client: 192.168.60.1, server: nexus.domain.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://192.168.60.204:8081/", host: "nexus.domain.com"
2020-06-26T13:14:52.105371984Z 192.168.60.1 - - [26/Jun/2020:13:14:52 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 560 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Fedora; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36" "-"
```

Comment: Open a shell in your nginx container and ping nexus.domain.com - what is the result?

Comment: Hi @Arik, tried that with `docker exec -t -i mycontainer /bin/bash`. `nginx:alpine` image doesn't seem to have a shell: `OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:346: starting container process caused "exec: \"/bin/bash\": stat /bin/bash: no such file or directory": unknown`

Comment: try `docker exec -it mycontainer sh`

Comment: @Arik. That worked. I can ping `nexus.domain.com` from nginx container. Question updated. Thanks.

Comment: try adding the following to the `server` block: `resolver 1.1.1.1 1.0.0.1 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 208.67.222.222 208.67.220.220 valid=60s;`

Comment: @Arik, Thanks again. Same issue. Question updated with results.

Answer (score 0):

It appears it was a DNS issue, which I don't fully understand, but would love to learn what the reason is.

Also, I was too quick on the refresh button. It takes about 15 - 30 seconds on my setup for both Nginx and Nexus to be fully up and running.

#### TL;DR:

Remove domain, changing: `proxy_pass http://nexus.domain.com:8081` to `proxy_pass http://nexus:8081`

#### Full story:

Bringing up a shell inside the Nginx container and pinging `nexus.domain.com` resolves the IP of the Docker host - which is what I thought I would want.

Pinging `nexus` resolves to the Docker internal IP address for this container.

It seems to be working without the `resolver` section. For completeness, here is my nginx.conf:

```
client_max_body_size      4G;

server {
  listen                  80;
  server_name             nexus.domain.com;
  location /  {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
  }
}

#resolver              1.1.1.1 1.0.0.1 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 208.67.222.222 208.67.220.220 valid=60s;

server {
  listen                  443 ssl;
  server_name             nexus.domain.com;

  ssl_certificate         /etc/nginx/certs/nexus.crt.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key     /etc/nginx/certs/nexus.key.pem;
  ssl_protocols           TLSv1.2;
  ssl_ciphers             HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;

  location / {
    proxy_pass            http://nexus:8081/;
    proxy_redirect        off;
    proxy_set_header      Host $http_host;
    #proxy_set_header      X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header      X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for; #Gets CSS working
    #proxy_set_header      X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    proxy_set_header      X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
  }
}
```

I'd love to know what's going on with DNS, if anyone has the time to explain...

HTH